# Error after embedding an app into a Safari extension bundle

Tags: macos, safari, bundle

I'm working on a Safari extension (.appex that is embedded in a .app). As soon as I just bundle an Electron .app inside the bundle, at Content/MacOS, without even calling it, the extension is not loaded by Safari with this in the log:

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.WebContent.18097): Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Library/Apple/System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/SafariShared.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.Safari.SearchHelper.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Library/Apple/System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.xpc
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.my.extension[18088]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by launchd[1]
```

What could be the problem?